# mysql problem connecting

Tags: 20.04, mysql

I want to open mysql and I cant.
I write this command in terminal: mysql -uroot -p
and the it says: Enter password
but I don't remember what the password is,so what can I do now?
Thanks.

Comment: If you need to connect to the root account in MySQL, you need to use this command: `sudo mysql`. That’s all. No need to enter a password (aside from your Ubuntu password).

Comment: When I type: sudo mysql ,I receive: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Have you customized your MySQL installation in some manner? There has been no password for `root` since 16.04. Only a manual override would set one 

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you may need to reset the root credential. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html